# Comparing ngfor old and new value on change detection

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor, angular-changedetection

Hi i need help on angular.
I have ngfor looping array from observable and this array changes periodically, now i want to compare old and new value of every list wen array change. The objective is to flash green on list item when value increased or red when value decreased..

```js
<div *ngfor="let item of items" >
<span class="" >{{item.price}}</span>
</div>
```

Span class must be "red" when item.price is less than previous value after change detection or must be green if more than previous value

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is using a method that compares new and old value.

***TS-File***

```
// your current items
const items: Array<Item> = [];

// a copy of the items which represent the previous state
const comparables: Array<Item> = [];


// Compare the price and return the corresponding CSS-class
getItemColor(item: Item): string {
     const oldItemIndex = this.comparables.findIndex(element => element.id === item.id);

     // a guard for preventing null and undefined problems
     if (oldItemIndex === -1) { return 'black' };
     
     const oldItem = this.comparables[oldItemIndex];
     
     if (item.price > oldItem.price) { return 'green' };
     if (item.price === oldItem.price) { return 'black' };
     if (item.price < oldItem.price) { return 'red' };
}

// inside your observable
value => {
     // JSON.parse/stringify is used to generate unique clones.
 
    // copy the current items into the list for old items
    this.comparables = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.items));

    // override the list for current items
    this.items = value;
}
```

***HTML***

```
<div *ngfor="let item of items" >
    <span [class]="getItemColor(item)">{{item.price}}</span>
</div>
```

***CSS***

And here you define the classes green, black and red

```
.red {
    color: red;
}

.black {
    color: black;
}

.green {
    color: green;
}
```